# Open a DBX and BAT Outlook Files

Tags: c++, outlook, batch-file, dbx

Hi guys I need to read some email from outlook in a C++ program, after that based on the content of email, I'll decide to reply or not.

I suppose I need to open Dbx outlook files, but how?

thx

Comment: Do you mean Outlook Express, as that's what uses DBX files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBX files are Jet Blue ESE database files You can find the documentation here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269245(EXCHG.10).aspx

Or you may find it easier to use the Outlook Express libraries directly:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb931229(VS.85).aspx

There currently appears to be a problem with the documentation, as all the interfaces state that they don't define any methods. However you can see all the methods in the left-hand-side of the scriptfree version.